# How to take by JQuery the ancestor-element of an html-element(PartialView)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to take the ancestor tag  of  tag. The  is located at View and Delete is located at partal view.

I am able to load an partial view into the view by AJAX. However I cannot take an ancestor of the partial view to manipulate a partial view, in my case, deleting a partial view.

**My partial View is:**

```
<img id="hello" src="@Url.Content("/content/images/" + @Model.Address)" />
<br />
<a id="linkToDel" onclick="clickme(this.id)">Delete</a>
```

**The View is:**

```
<div id="imageDivFirst"></div>
```

**JavaScript to load a partial view:**

```
$('#imageDivFirst').load('/Home/ImagePartialView', { address: data.result.name });
```

What I've tried to get an ancestor of partial view:

```
function clickme(id) {
var a = document.getElementById("linkToDel").previousElementSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling;// not detected an ancestor
} 
//then I want to take an ancestor of <a id="linkToDel"/> 
// and delete the partial view
```

**How to get this ancestor located at View:**

```
<div id="imageDivFirst"></div>//How to get this ancestor located at View?
```

Comment: you can use id directly to get jquery object and remove it `$('#imageDivFirst').remove()`

Comment: Whats wrong with just `$('#imageDivFirst').empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the element reference

```
<a id="linkToDel" onclick="clickme(this)">Delete</a>
```

then

```
function clickme(el) {
    var a = el.parentNode;//parent element
    $(el).parent().remove();//using jQuery to remove the parent element
    $(el).parent().empty();//to remove the partial contents only, but the parent element will remain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can use `closest()` for this:

```
$("#linkToDel").closest("#imageDivFirst")
```

But make sure you don't have multiple elements with same id in your html, other wise it will create issues, if there can be multiple elements, then use class attribute of element not id.

Comment: i think `imageDivFirst` is sibling and not parent

Comment: i don't think his anchor tag is inside that div so that div is parent so ``closest()`` will get it